# Getting duplicate results on firestore query?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display posts of users you are following, including your posts.

First, I have a collection of all the users the current user is following. I get this collection:

```
Firebase.firestore()
.collection('following')
.doc(Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection('following');
```

This returns the collection of users that the current user is following. Now, I need to pull each post for each user using this query:

```
    querySnapshot.forEach(async (res) => {
        await Firebase.firestore()
        .collection('globalPosts')
        .where("uid", "in", [res.data().uid, Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid])
```

I had the logic separated (first push the current user's posts to the array, then go one by one through each "following" user and pull their posts).

But now I want to do lazy loading for these posts, so decided to combine the query into one.
This has caused the current user's posts to be duplicated. How can I remove the duplicates?

EDIT: this is how I was doing it originally, First getting all the current users posts, then each of the following users posts one by one which worked with no duplicates

```
 await Firebase.firestore()
    .collection('globalPosts')
    .where("uid", "==", Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
     .onSnapshot(function(query) {
        query.forEach((doc) =>  {
             const { 
                 ..Fields
                } = doc.data();
    
                followingPosts.push({
                ..Fields
                 });
         })
    
     });

    querySnapshot.forEach(async (res) => {
        await Firebase.firestore()
        .collection('globalPosts')
        .where("uid", "in", res.data().uid)
        .onSnapshot(function(query) {
            query.forEach((doc) =>  {
                const { 
                    ..Fields
                    } = doc.data();

        
                    followingPosts.push({
                    ..Fields
                    });
                
            })
            followingPosts.sort(function(a,b){ 

                return b.date_created.toDate() - a.date_created.toDate()
        
            })
        
        });

    });

    this.setState({
        followingPosts,
        isLoading: false,   
    });
```

Comment: could you share the combined query with your first logic query? it may give some more detail for viewers.

Comment: @MuthuThavamani added the code!